# Question about Context Manager: how to link two objects in an elegant way

Tags: python, object

I was reading the documentation of TensorFlow and I have found this code

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  c = tf.constant(5.0)
  assert c.graph is g
```

`tf.Graph().as_default()` returns a context manager and whatever is define below the `with` statement acquires an attribute `graph` that stores the object `g`.

I don't quite understand how the object `c` and `g` gets linked to each other, since in the definition of `c` we are not passing the object `g`. Can you explain me how Python makes the link between the objects? This question is not specific to TensorFlow - I am just using it as an example.

More specifically, I would like to create two classes `A` and `B` where `A` implements a Context Manager, something along the lines of the following code

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        # something here

    def __exit__(self):
        # something here



class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
```

Then, I would like to make the following code work

```
obj = A()
with obj as a:
    b = B()
    assert b.a is obj
```

Comment: From what I can see, TensorFlow sets and retrieves a graph context located somewhere *not* in Python code (`tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe`), so there's a global state somewhere in the Python session which TensorFlow objects have access to. While I don't doubt that it executes fine and there's a lot of design considerations going on, from purely an API point of view I don't think this is actually elegant - the fact that there's no API link between `c.graph` and `g`, yet they compare identically, raises more questions than anything else.